# Excel or VBA - If values in column match, compare values in another column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In the example below, for values in column A that are the same, compare values in column B with values in column C and flag matched values.  In the example, rows 2 and 3 would be flagged.  Thanks!

[example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMCDW.png)

Comment: How would the be flagged?

Comment: share your cells structure to find out your problem

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional formatting with a custom formula of:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$C:$C,$B1)>0
```

Applied to `A:B`

[image]